# how to find a one threshold value for large number of images :opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, feature-extraction, threshold

My project need to extract features to classify diseases of leaves. So it require to extract features from nearly 800 images , can anyone help me to find the optimal one threshold value that suits for all the images, I tried otsu thresholding but I am not sure whether I can use this for find optimal threshold value that suits for all the images.My knowledge about image processing is low , so sorry for asking poor questions, but if someone can help me , it's a big encouragement for me to continue my project. Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: There is no such thing as "optimal threshold" for all images. Threshold value depends on the content, lighting conditions and end result of each image.

Comment: @Zindarod Thank you

Comment: Just to give a little context into what Otsu thresholding does so you can get a better idea. Suppose you make a histogram of the intensities of each pixel in the image. There's usually two large bumps in the histograms: one for light values, one for dark. [Example](https://imgur.com/a/c3KHy). Otsu's method finds the optimal splitting point between these for automatic thresholding in an image. But it's not always separated super well, so it really depends on the image. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) for the general background of Otsu's method.

Comment: try to use image equalization and normalization techniques to normalize color of your ROI. Then use histogram based thresholding or Otsu thresholding method..